# Join tables from two different clusters on Vertica

Tags: vertica

I am looking a way to join two tables on two different Vertica clusters, Out of box without using any third party tools.

I failed to find any relevant resource. 
Help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Vertica? Same cluster config? How the two clusters are connected? How big are the two tables? What did you try so far?

Comment: @mauro: Vertica version : Vertica Analytic Database v8.1.0-5.
One table is 50 TB and another table is 50GB. I need to check on how two clusters are connected. I am exploring options on joining tables.

Comment: **Update**  
In my organization, they use cisco composite to perform this operation, where tables are published to composite and join is performed in top of it. I could not find any info from Vertica documentation.

i will keep posted on updates.

Comment: Well I don't know cisco composite. In general terms I would replicate (and keep in synch) a copy of the smaller table on the cluster where the bigger table is and run the join there. I doubt we can find a more efficient/faster solution.

Comment: @mauro : 
"We don't currently have any federation (cross cluster queries) functionality in Vertica, " this is reply i received from Vertica forums.
Other option is to use "COPY FROM VERTICA".

Comment: Yes, exactly... use COPY FROM VERTICA to replicate the smaller table from one cluster to another and run your join where the bigger table is located.